# Weird traingles shading after importing obj

Tags: modeling

I have used a plugin to export from Sketchup to Blender and I get this weird shading.

I have tried recalculating normals but didn't do the job.

I have also marked sharp seams as smooth but then the pattern just had changed but no real improvement.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try applying an edgesplit modifier

Comment: Try to detail which plugin you used, and maybe import settings.

Comment: Can you upload your blend file so we can look at it?

Grab the URL of the question

Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Select the blend file

Add the url of the question

Grab the url that results

Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: That looks like an import problem I had yonks ago - it was fixed by turning the "Auto Smooth" box off.  In the object's properties at right, the little triangle icon.